# how to add a time delay using JAVA

Tags: java, automated-tests

I am trying to insert a time delay of 5/10 seconds after navigating to Facebook, but this is not working:

```
public FacebookLoginPage clickSignInWithFacebook() {
        WebElement facebookBtn = waitForElementDisplay(loginPageObjects.signInWithFacebookBtn);
        facebookBtn.click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        return FacebookLoginPage.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

`Thread.sleep(milliseconds);`

So for your case:

`Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: I have tried this but get the following:

Error:(75, 21) java: unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: You can either add `throws InterruptedException` to your method or use a try/catch block to handle the exception.